# Linq Max: The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple LINQ that gets the max value from table

```
decimal? taskId = dbContext.My_Tasks.Max(m=> m.TaskId)
```

It works fine when table has at least one record, but when table is empty it returns **The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null**

**Now my question is**: how to check on just one Linq if the table has records an return the max id?.

Comment: If no records i need 1 as result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.110).aspx), with a value of 1 in your case. Something like:

`dbContext.My_Tasks.Select(m => m.TaskId).DefaultIfEmpty(1).Max()`

This will produce a collection with a value of 1 if there are no tasks, and the `Max` of 1 is, well, 1.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to a `decimal?` before `max()`ing it:

```
decimal? taskId = dbContext.My_Tasks
    .Cast<int?>()
    .Max();
```